# Price Variations

Tags: javascript, jquery

So how would one in JavaScript or with the added help of jQuery be able to get price variations. For example the first item is a set base at $450 and every item after that is a additional $150. But here is the trick the client is able to change that price so $450 is now $225 and additional is $75. I know how to do this with a bunch of if else statements but that just seems messy. Is there a better way?

Here's my code so far it only does the divided by two part but not the additions.

Edit: Further explanation of how this works

item#1 450
item#2 150
item#3 150
full[x] half[ ]

item#1 225
item#2 75
item#3 75
full[ ] half[x]

each additional is actually the base divided by 3 so 450 = 150 and 225 = 75
 and the half is the original base 450 / 2 = 225

```
var dropResult;
$(function (){
        $(".t").click(function(){
        dropResult = $("input[name=drop]:checked").val();
        dropCalculate();
        });
});

function dropCalculate() {
var dropPrice = 450;
    var dropAmount = $(".itemadd", "#items").length;
    $("#dropAmount").html("Total: " + dropAmount);
    if (dropResult == 1) {
        dropTotal = dropAmount * dropPrice;
        $("#dropPrice").html("Price Total: $" + dropTotal.toFixed(2));
    }else {
        dropTotal = dropAmount * dropPrice / 2;
        $("#dropPrice").html("Price Total: $" + dropTotal.toFixed(2));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle.com or a codepen.io? I'm a little confused on what you're asking.

Comment: one thing you could do is applying the drop on the total

dropTotal = dropAmount * dropPrice;

if (dropResult != 1) {
        dropTotal = dropTotal  / 2;    
 } 

$("#dropPrice").html("Price Total: $" + dropTotal.toFixed(2));

Comment: Can't as the back end is python with a mySQL data base. Um let me see how to explain this a little better. so basically what this does is it adds all the items from a list so if there is only one item on the list it adds 450 and the client has a radio button that changes the price to half. Now my issue is how would i make every any additional  items a different price based on the radio input with out having to do a bunch of if else statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so if I understand you correctly, you want to apply a discount to the given price in a clean manner, depending on the number of items. I'd first start by applying the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle to your code, and putting variables in local scope:

```
//var dropResult = $("input[name=drop]:checked").val();
//this line doesn't actually do anything, so I removed it. It will always return true, as you're using the :checked pseudo-selector to only select checked checkboxes.

$(function (){
    $(".t").click(function(){
      dropCalculate(450);
    });
});

function dropCalculate(dropPrice) {
    var dropAmount = $(".itemadd", "#items").length,
        dropTotal = dropAmount * dropPrice;

    if (dropResult != 1) {
        dropTotal = dropTotal / 2;
    }

    $("#dropPrice").html("Price Total: $" + dropTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

Which is a lot cleaner. Then, if you have more complex discount rules, or multiple rules for multiple products, you can use an object for that. Here is a simple example of that:

```
$(function (){
    $(".t").click(function(){
      var pricesObj = {
          'default': 75,
          '1':450,
          '2':225
      };

      dropCalculate(pricesObj);
    });
});

function dropCalculate(priceObj) {
    var dropAmount = $(".itemadd", "#items").length;

    if (priceObj[dropAmount]) {
        dropTotal = priceObj[dropAmount] * dropAmount;
    }
    else{
        dropTotal = priceObj['default'] * dropAmount;
    }

    $("#dropPrice").html("Price Total: $" + dropTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

If you need any help understanding that, just ask!

Update: I misunderstood your use case, but this should still point you in the right direction. In my code, if there is 1 product, the price is 450, 2 is 225, and more is 75 each.

Comment: I will try this out and yes i think this is pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Hey james can you have a look over here i revised my code but im running into some other problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680499/pricing-variations-v2

Answer (score 0):

a quick change you could make, it's something like that:

```
dropTotal = dropAmount * dropPrice; 

$("#dropPrice").html("Price Total: $" + dropResult == 1 ? dropTotal.toFixed(2)) : (dropTotal / 2).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zvashxu/3/)

```
 $('#dropPrice').text( '$' + (450 + ((450 * ($('#items .itemadd').length - 1)) / 3)) / (Number($("input[name=drop]").is(':checked')) + 1));
```

Comment: and here is a function if you need it as a function `function Calculate()
{
    var dropPrice = 450;
    var itemsCount = $('#items .itemadd').length;
    var haveDiscount = $("input[name=drop]").is(':checked');
    
    var Total = (450 + ((450 * (itemsCount - 1)) / 3)) / (Number(haveDiscount) + 1);
    $('#dropPrice').text("Price Total: $" + Total);
}`   and here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zvashxu/6/)